# refresh datatable automatic when any change happen in object in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

i am able to refresh view page using actionpoller at some interval time in salesforce but

i want to **refresh** my **datatable**, only when any changes made to the object that is bind to my view page like insert , update ,delete happen to object must reflect my datatable automatically.

please guide me..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Force.com Streaming API for this. **Force.com Streaming API Developer's Guide** contains the details regarding how to use it along with a example of refreshing a Visualforce page automatically using streaming api.